# Mongodb wildcard index not being used for $ne query

Tags: mongodb

I just found out that wildcard index on mongodb 4.2, doing a `COLLSCAN` for `$ne` query.
So I was wondering, whether I did something wrong, or it was currently not being supported. And here I was looking a solution to use indexing for my ever growing (unstructured) `extra` field while using `$ne` operation. Because my `extra` field will store many kind of key-value string data.

This is my query,

```
db.coll.explain(true).find({"extra.tag": {$ne: "dummy-tag"}})
```

And here's is the `explain()` result,

```
"executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true, 
        "nReturned" : 10133998.0, 
        "executionTimeMillis" : 5018.0, 
        "totalKeysExamined" : 0.0, 
        "totalDocsExamined" : 10184077.0, 
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "COLLSCAN", 
            "filter" : {
                "extra.tag" : {
                    "$not" : {
                        "$eq" : "dummy-tag"
                    }
                }
            }, 
            "nReturned" : 10133998.0, 
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 394.0, 
            "works" : 10184079.0, 
            "advanced" : 10133998.0, 
            "needTime" : 50080.0, 
            "needYield" : 0.0, 
            "saveState" : 10184.0, 
            "restoreState" : 10184.0, 
            "isEOF" : 1.0, 
            "direction" : "forward", 
            "docsExamined" : 10184077.0
        }, 
        "allPlansExecution" : [

        ]
},
```

This is how I create my wildcard index

```
db.coll.createIndex({"extra.$**": 1})
```

Indexes on my collection

```
"indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 102354944.0, 
        ...
        ...
        ...
        "extra.$**_1" : 110243840.0
 },
```

*Update:
Sample of document, because the nature of our data, I omit some of the value

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c582f5577612608f3e6a333"), 
    "email" : "", 
    "createdAt" : ISODate(), 
    "name" : "" , 
    "firstname" : "", 
    "lastname" : "", 
    "birthDate" : ISODate(),
    "gender" : "", 
    "phone" : "", 
    "city" : "", 
    "country" : "",
    "company" : "", 
    "labels" : [
        "dummy-label"
    ], 
    "index" : 0.0,  
    "state" : "ACTIVE", 
    "extra" : {
        "tag" : "dummy-tag", 
        "note" : "dummy note"
    }
}
```

Please let me know If I'm not clear enough with my question.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us one document?

Comment: Hi @Gibbs, I just put a sample of my document

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation

> More selective queries match a smaller percentage of documents. For instance, an equality match on the unique _id field is highly selective as it can match at most one document.

> Less selective queries match a larger percentage of documents. Less selective queries cannot use indexes effectively or even at all.

[Reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/#read-operations-query-selectivity)

`$ne` is also less selective queries as mentioned [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
Sadly to say, I already knew that `$ne`, is not quite good for selectivity, But here I was looking for a way to use $ne while using wildcard index. You could say `$ne` already set in stone. What makes me wondering was wildcard index work as expected without $ne operation, but using `$ne` gave me `COLLSCAN` query plan. Also in [mongodb's wildcard-index docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-wildcard/) there were no statement regarding $ne for non-null query restriction. Happy to be corrected :)